Special determinant formula
Consider two column vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ of length $k$ and $m$ respectively, $km$ variables denoted $y_{i,j}$ (i=1 to k, j=1 to m), and a quadratic form $\mathbf{y}^{T}\mathbb{M}\mathbf{y}$ where $$\mathbb{M}=\mathbb{D}_{1/a}\otimes\mathbb{D}_{1/b}+t(\mathbf{1}_{k}\mathbf{1}_{k}^{T}\otimes\mathbb{D}_{1/b}+\mathbb{D}_{1/a}\otimes\mathbf{1}_{m}\mathbf{1}_{m}^{T})$$with $\mathbb{D}_{1/a}$ being a $k$ by $k$ main-diagonal matrix with $1/a_i$ on the main digagonal and analogously with $\mathbb{D}_{1/b}$, while $\mathbf{1}_k$ is a column vector of length $k$ with all elements equal to $1$ (analogously for $\mathbf{1}_m$). Using results of my inquiry "Prove a special determinant formula" one can show that the determinant of $\mathbb{M}$ is
$$(1+t*\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{1}_m)^{k-1}(1+t*\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{1}_k)^{m-1}(1+t*(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{1}_k+\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{1}_m))/(\prod{a_i})^{m}/(\prod{b_j
})^k.$$
My new question is: suppose we replace  $y_{k,m}$ (the last of our variables) by minus the sum of all the remaining $y_{i,j}$'s; we get a new quadratic form in the remaining $km-1$ variables. How does one prove that the determinant of the new ($km-1$ by $km-1$) matrix of coefficients is
$$(1+t*\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{1}_m)^{k-1}(1+t*\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{1}_k)^{m-1}(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{1}_k)(\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{1}_m)/(\prod{a_i})^{m}/(\prod{b_j
})^k?$$
This has been posted on the Mathematics site for 3 months with no response; I hope someone can help me here.

The mathstack post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4962085/determinant-of-a-special-quadratic-form

Your formulas for the matrix M and its determinant make no reference to the y variables. But somehow you derived your new matrix from the old one using these variable. Please explain this process, or better, give an explicit formula for the new matrix, if possible.

The new M matrix is simply the old one without the last row and the last column - it is possible to spell it out explicitly, but the expression is rather long - I am still working on the proof of my statement (closing in, I hope).

For $t=0$, your proposed formula does not reduce to the product of diagonal entries in $D_{1/a}\otimes D_{1/b}$ without its last row and column so something has to be wrong.

Updated with proof.
Let $M(i)$ denote the matrix $M$ with its $i$th row and column deleted. Then
for the matrix $M$ in the question, the determinant after deletion of the $
mk $th (last) row is
$$
\left\vert M(mk)\right\vert =\frac{a_{k}b_{m}\left( 1+ta^{T}1_{k}\right)
^{m-2}\left( 1+tb^{T}1_{m}\right) ^{k-2}f}{\left( \prod a_{i}\right)
^{m}\left( \prod b_{i}\right) ^{k}}
$$
where
\begin{align}
f &=\left( a^{T}1_{k}-a_{k}\right) \left( b^{T}1_{m}-b_{m}\right) \left(
a^{T}1_{k}+b^{T}1_{m}\right) t^{3} \\
&+\left( 3\left( a^{T}1_{k}-a_{k}\right) \left( b^{T}1_{m}-b_{m}\right)
+\left( a^{T}1_{k}-a_{k}\right) ^{2}+\left( b^{T}1_{m}-b_{m}\right)
^{2}+\left( a_{k}+b_{m}\right) \left(
a^{T}1_{k}-a_{k}+b^{T}1_{m}-b_{m}\right) +a_{k}b_{m}\right) t^{2} \\
&+\left( 2\left( a^{T}1_{k}+b^{T}1_{m}\right) -(a_{k}+b_{m})\right) t+1.
\end{align}
Preliminaries
The approach will be to first find the eigenvectors of a matrix congruent to
$M$, and then convert them to eigenvectors of the submatrix. We will make
frequent use of the mixed-product property of the Kronecker product, $\left(
A\otimes B\right) \left( C\otimes D\right) =AC\otimes BD$. Let $J_{m}$ be
the $m\times m$ matrix of $1$s. We will require the eigenvalues and
eigenvectors of $
D_{b}^{1/2}J_{m}D_{b}^{1/2}=(D_{b}^{1/2}1_{m})(D_{b}^{1/2}1_{m})^{T}$.  This is
a rank 1 matrix with $m-1$ zero eigenvalues, and non-zero eigenvalue $
(D_{b}^{1/2}1_{m})^{T}(D_{b}^{1/2}1_{m})=b^{T}1_{m}$ with corresponding
eigenvector $D_{b}^{1/2}1_{m}$.
The matrix of (column) eigenvectors is
chosen in the form
$$
V_{m}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}^{1/2}b_{m}^{-1/2} & -1_{m-1}D_{b}^{1/2}(1) \\ 
D_{b}^{1/2}(1)1_{m-1} & I_{m-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the first row and column have been partitioned out, and the
eigenvectors are scaled so their last entries are $1$ (first and last
eigenvector) or zero (others). The diagonal matrix of eigenvalues is $
\Lambda _{m}=\operatorname{diag}(b^{T}1_{m},0,\dotsc ,0)$. It is convenient to
orthogonalize this matrix using Gram Schmidt to give $U_{m}$. $U_{m}$ has
the same zero/nonzero pattern as $V_{m}$ in its last row, namely only the
first and last entries are nonzero. Since the first column is just
normalized in the orthogonalization, its last entry becomes $\beta
_{1}:=b_{m}^{1/2}/(b^{T}1_{m})^{1/2}$. Then considering the normalization of
the last row shows the last entry in the last row is $\beta
_{2}:=(b^{T}1_{m}-b_{m})^{1/2}/(b^{T}1_{m})^{1/2}$. Similarly for $
D_{a}^{1/2}J_{k}D_{a}^{1/2}$, the first and last entries in the last row of $
U_{k}$ are $\alpha _{1}:=a_{k}^{1/2}/(a^{T}1_{k})^{1/2}$ and $\alpha
_{2}:=(a^{T}1_{k}-a_{k})^{1/2}/(a^{T}1_{k})^{1/2}$.
Proof
Consider the first matrix $M=D_{1/a}\otimes D_{1/b}+t(J_{k}\otimes
D_{1/b}+D_{1/a}\otimes J_{m}$. Pre- and postmultiply it by $
D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes D_{b}^{1/2}$, which multiplies the determinant by $\left(
\prod a_{i}\right) ^{m}\left( \prod b_{i}\right) ^{k}$, to give the matrix
\begin{align}
N &=I_{mk}+t\left( \left( D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes D_{b}^{1/2}\right) \left(
J_{k}\otimes D_{1/b}\right) \left( D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes D_{b}^{1/2}\right) \right. \\
&+ \left. \left( D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes D_{b}^{1/2}\right) \left( D_{1/a}\otimes
J_{m}\right) \left( D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes D_{b}^{1/2}\right) \right) \\
&=I_{mk}+t\left( D_{a}^{1/2}J_{k}D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes I_{m}+I_{k}\otimes
D_{b}^{1/2}J_{m}D_{b}^{1/2}\right).
\end{align}
We carry out a similarity with $I_{k}\otimes U_{m}$ (inverse $I_{k}\otimes
U_{m}^{-1}= I_{k}\otimes U_{m}^{T}$) to give $N_{2}$
\begin{align}
N_{2} &=I_{mk}+t\left( \left( I_{k}\otimes U_{m}^{-1}\right) \left(
D_{a}^{1/2}J_{k}D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes I_{m}\right) \left( I_{k}\otimes
U_{m}\right) \right. \\
 &+ \left. I_{k}\otimes U_{m}^{-1}\left( I_{k}\otimes
D_{b}^{1/2}J_{m}D_{b}^{1/2}\right) \left( I_{k}\otimes U_{m}\right) \right)
\\
&=I_{mk}+t\left( D_{a}^{1/2}J_{k}D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes I_{m}+I_{k}\otimes
\Lambda _{m}\right)
\end{align}
which has the effect of diagonalizing the diagonal $m\times m$ blocks
originating from the third term and leaving the other blocks unchanged
(these were already diagonal). Now we carry out a second similarity with $
U_{k}\otimes I_{m}$ to give the diagonal matrix $N_{3}$
\begin{align}
N_{3} &=I_{mk}+t\left( \left( U_{k}^{-1}\otimes I_{m}\right) \left(
D_{a}^{1/2}J_{k}D_{a}^{1/2}\otimes I_{m}\right) \left( U_{k}\otimes
I_{m}\right) \right. \\
&+ \left. \left( U_{k}^{-1}\otimes I_{m}\right) \left( I_{k}\otimes
\Lambda _{m}\right) \left( U_{k}\otimes I_{m}\right) \right) \\
&=I_{mk}+t\left( \Lambda _{k}\otimes I_{m}+I_{k}\otimes \Lambda _{m}\right).
\end{align}
The eigenvalues are in the diagonal entries. The identity $I_{mk}$
contributes $1$ to every diagonal entry, every $m\times m$ diagonal block
has an additional $b^{T}1_{m}$ in its $(1,1)$ entry, and the first block has
an additional $a^{T}1_{k}$ in each diagonal entry. The eigenvalues are $
\left( 1+ta^{T}1_{k}+tb^{T}1_{m}\right) $ with multiplicity $1$, $\left(
1+ta^{T}1_{k}\right) $ with multiplicity $m-1$, $\left( 1+tb^{T}1_{m}\right) 
$ with multiplicity $k-1$, and $1$ with multiplicity $km-m-k+1$. (The
eigenvalues of the Kronecker sum $\Lambda _{k}\otimes I_{m}+I_{k}\otimes
\Lambda _{m}$ are the $mk$ possible sums of the eigenvalues of $\Lambda _{k} 
$ with the eigenvalues of $\Lambda _{m}$ [1].) The product of the
eigenvalues of $N$ (or $N_{3}$) gives the determinant of $N$, which leads to
the determinant of $M$ previously deduced. The orthogonal matrix of
eigenvectors is the product of the two similarity matrices, $\left(
I_{k}\otimes U_{m}\right) \left( U_{k}\otimes I_{m}\right) =U_{k}\otimes
U_{m}=:U$.
We know by Cauchy interlacing [2], that $N(mk)$ must have eigenvalues $
\left( 1+ta^{T}1_{k}\right) $ with multiplicity $m-2$, $\left(
1+tb^{T}1_{m}\right) $ with multiplicity $k-2$, and $1$ with multiplicity $
km-m-k$. It remains to find the three remaining eigenvalues. (Actually, we
will only find their product.) As a consequence of its construction, the
matrix $U$ has four columns with their last entry nonzero, namely columns $
1$, $m$, $mk-m+1$, and $mk$; the others have zero as the last entry. These
correspond to eigenvalues $1+a^{T}1_{k}+b^{T}1_{m}$, $1+a^{T}1_{k}$, $
1+b^{T}1_{m}$, and $1$ respectively. The other columns with last entry zero
correspond to eigenvalues we already know by Cauchy interlacing are
eigenvalues of $N(mk)$. Deleting their last entries makes them eigenvectors
of $N(mk)$.
Consider now the matrix $Q_{1}$ below with the same determinant as $N(mk)$,
partitioned to show its last row and column.
$$
Q_{1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
N(mk) & 0 \\ 
0^{T} & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to see that the eigenvectors of $N$ with last entry zero are also
eigenvectors of $Q_{1}$, with the same eigenvalue. Therefore in the
similarity $Q=U^{T}Q_{1}U$ the corresponding diagonal entry is the
eigenvalue and the rest of the entries in that row (and column) are zero.
That eigenvalue is a factor in the determinant. Deleting these rows and
columns leaves a $4\times 4$ submatrix $S$ whose determinant is the
remaining part ($f$ above) of the determinant, i.e. the submatrix lying in
the intersection of the rows and columns $1,m,mk-m+1$, and $mk$ of $Q$. For
two eigenvectors $[u_{i}^{T},z_{i}]^{T}$ and $[u_{j}^{T},z_{j}]^{T}$, $
Q_{ij} $ is explicitly calculated as
$$
Q_{ij}=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{i}^{T} & z_{i}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
N(mk) & 0 \\ 
0^{T} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{j} \\ 
z_{j}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{i}^{T} & z_{i}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
N(mk)u_{j} \\ 
z_{j}
\end{bmatrix}
=u_{i}^{T}N(mk)u_{j}+z_{i}z_{j}.
$$
However, $[u_{j}^{T},z_{j}]^{T}$ is an eigenvector of $N$ with eigenvalue $
\lambda _{j}$ so we consider $N[u_{j}^{T},z_{j}]^{T}=\lambda
_{j}[u_{j}^{T},z_{j}]^{T}$ in partitioned form,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
N(mk) & n \\ 
n^{T} & w
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{j} \\ 
z_{j}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
N(mk)u_{j}+z_{j}n \\ 
n^{T}u_{j}+wz_{j}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda _{j}u_{j} \\ 
\lambda _{j}z_{j}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to find $N(mk)u_{j}=\lambda _{j}u_{j}-z_{j}n$ and $n^{T}u_{j}=\lambda
_{j}z_{j}-wz_{j}$. From orthogonality of the eigenvectors we have $
u_{i}^{T}u_{j}+z_{i}z_{j}=\delta _{ij}$ where $\delta _{ij}$ is the
Kronecker delta. Therefore we may rewrite
\begin{align}
Q_{ij} &=u_{i}^{T}\left( \lambda _{j}u_{j}-z_{j}n\right)
+z_{i}z_{j}=\lambda _{j}\left( \delta _{ij}-z_{i}z_{j}\right)
-z_{j}u_{i}^{T}n+z_{i}z_{j} \\
&=\lambda _{j}\left( \delta _{ij}-z_{i}z_{j}\right) -z_{j}\left( \lambda
_{i}z_{i}-wz_{i}\right) +z_{i}z_{j} \\
&=\lambda _{i}\delta _{ij}+z_{i}z_{j}(1+w-\lambda _{i}-\lambda _{j}).
\end{align}
The last entries in $U$ for the eigenvectors with nonzero last entries may
be found from the definition of the Kronecker product and are tabulated
below. The last entry of $N$ is $w=1+t(a_{k}+b_{m})$. The information
required to calculate $S$ using the above formula is given in the table.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\text{index in } S & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\text{index in } Q & 1 & m & mk-m+1 & mk \\ 
\lambda  \text{ (in }N \text{)} & 1+ta^{T}1_{k}+tb^{T}1_{m} & 1+ta^{T}1_{k} & 
1+tb^{T}1_{m} & 1 \\ 
z & \alpha _{1}\beta _{1} & \alpha _{1}\beta _{2} & \alpha _{2}\beta
_{1} & \alpha _{2}\beta _{2}
\end{array}
$$
Explicit calculation of the $4\times 4$ determinant gives the expression for $f$ given
above. Division by the product $\left( \prod a_{i}\right) ^{m}\left( \prod
b_{i}\right) ^{k}$ to convert from $\left\vert N(mk)\right\vert $ to $
\left\vert M(mk)\right\vert $ incorrectly includes the last element $
a_{k}b_{m}$ of $D_{a}\otimes D_{b}$ and so the result is multiplied by $
a_{k}b_{m}$ to compensate for this, giving the final result shown.
[1] R.A. Horn, C.R. Johnson, Matrix Analysis, Cambridge University Press,
1985, Thm. 4.3.8, p. 185.
[2] R.A. Horn, C.R. Johnson, Topics in Matrix Analysis, Cambridge University
Press, 1991, Thm. 4.4.5, p. 268.

I think I can prove this but will need to work with the eigenvectors, which will be fiddly, so may take a few days,

Nice observation by @dharr.   PS  In addition to a determinant, I'll also need the inverse.

For the inverse, it's not clear what form you want, which presumably depends
on what you want to do with it.. Now that you have the determinant, the
simplest is just the adjugate divided by the determinant. If you want a
formula in terms of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, $M(mk)^{-1}=U^{T}
\Lambda ^{-1}U$ (different $U$ than in my answer), then finding the last
eigenvectors is non-trivial and involves roots of a cubic.
